# JMeter script - not downloading png, jpg, woff

Tags: jmeter, png, jpeg, woff

My JMeter script doesnt download woff, png, jpg. I checked script and all of config elements, no where I am specifying not to downlaod them but still it's not downloading them. Can anyone tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "specify to download them", JMeter won't do it automatically.

1. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element (if it's not there yet)
2. On "Advanced" tab tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files` and `Use concurrent pool`

   [image]
3. It's also a good idea to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to replicate browser behaviour when it comes to handling resources [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I know about Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files and Use concurrent pool. ..I also have Cache Manager but still it' not downloading png, jpg, woff. ..If I record script using HTTP script recorder, then it records png,jpg,woff.

Comment: I am having same problem. I am able to retrieve html/ js/ css/ ico resources, but cannot fetch related images (png/jpg/font files) - Using latest stable JMeter (5.4.3). Were you able to fix that issue? (ps. option for Embedded Resources etc is active)